Unity3D VRアプリでオブジェクトをどこでもつかめるようにしたい
Unity3Dで開発しているVRアプリにおいて、つかめるオブジェクトの一部しかつかめないという問題が発生しています。オブジェクト全体をどこでもつかめるようにするには、どのような方法を取ればよいでしょうか？
追記
対象オブジェクトにはXR Grab Netowork Interactableをアタッチしております．

「つかむ」は、どう実現しているのですか？それによって対応方法も変わると思います。

@hiromasamasuda
追記いたします．
